# How can I send some udp via python to a web domain?

Tags: python, http, udp

So currently I am trying to send udp to a server with a web domain like this
`www.example.com/path?stuff=exist`
I am currently trying to use socket
and this is is an example of my code

```
import socket

IPADDR = '64.233.177.139'

that is the ip of google, and not the ip I am currently trying to send to

PORTNUM = 9001

PACKETDATA = '42["message","test"]'

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, 0)
s.connect((IPADDR, PORTNUM, '/path?stuff=exist'))
s.send(PACKETDATA)`
```

And I currently get this error
`TypeError: getsockaddrarg() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`

I am new to using the socket library and did some digging to no avail.

For some more context I just want to send the data in `PACKETDATA` to the server `google.com/path?stuff=exist` (not really that url, just an example)
Anything helps, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate programming problem is that `socket.connect` expects to be called with an argument that is a tuple containing exactly two items -- a hostname (or IP address) string and a port number.  But this program passes an argument tuple that contains 3 items -- a host address, a port number *and* the string `'/path?stuff=exist'`.  That's why the error message complains about finding 3 things where only 2 were expected.

If you want to send `'/path?stuff=exist'` over UDP then you'll have to include it in the data portion of the datagram.  You'll also have to come up with some way of making it distinguishable from the `PACKETDATA` that you're already putting into the datagram body.  (That doesn't need to be fancy.  You could just insert a space between the path string and the `PACKETDATA`.)

There might also be a conceptual problem here.  A web server only listens for TCP traffic.  It does not listen for UDP traffic.  So unless you've arranged for your specific server to have some sort of listener accepting datagrams on the target UDP port, nothing at the server side will collect this traffic even after you've figured out how to get Python to send it.